# Chrome - declaring variables within functions arguments

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, variables

I've got an very annoying error, and I couldn't find anything on Google.

The following code works on Firefox, but Chrome returns the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ='

```
test = function(test = 'test'){};
```

My Chrome version is 23.0.1271.97 - any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: i'm surprised that it works on firefox, but why do you want to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not "declaring variables" - it's rather be described as "setting default values for the function's parameters". Consider this:

```
var x = 3;
var test = function(x = 4){
  console.log(x)
};
console.log(x); // 3
test();         // 4
test(5);        // 5
```

In other words, `x` declared in that function expression is local to this function.

It can be useful, agreed, but at present Firefox is the *only* browser that supports this feature (a part of ES6 draft specification).

To be more precise, it's only Firefox 15+, as shown at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters).

Comment: I understand. Is there any other way to set default values (except declaring them in the function itself with an if)?

Comment: None that I aware of. The common way is using `var === void(0) && (var = default_value)`, I suppose. But you shouldn't redeclare them: all function's parameter names are already defined in its variable context (as local variables).

Comment: Hmm. I'll think of a workaround. Just a few more lines of code, than :) Thank you!